# bootstrap modals put values in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a modal with an `input` to add a new category and at the same time to check if this value is already in my database and show me a message.

the main code is this Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#savebutton").click(function() {
    var name_category = $("#new_category").val();
    if (name_category != "") {
      alert("has values");
      $.post("action.php", {
        suggestion: name_location
      }, function(data, status) {
        $("#test").html(data);
      });
    } else {
      alert("give category");
    }
  });
});
```

and the PHP code is

```
$connection = sqlsrv_connect($server, $cinfo);
if( $connection === false )
{
    echo "Error (sqlsrv_connect): " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
}

if(isset($_POST['suggestion']))
{                       
    $query = "SELECT jacat_title FROM JobAdCategories WHERE jacat_title='".$_POST['suggestion']."'";
    $statement=sqlsrv_query($connection,$query);                        
    if(sqlsrv_num_rows($statement) > 0) {
        echo"Yes";                              
     } else {
         echo"No";
    }                           
}
sqlsrv_close($connection);
```

Comment: And what is your question ? is it not working ?

Comment: Which version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: bootstrap version v3.3.7...it is not working because when im trying to insert a value that i already have in my database the message is no again and again and i don't know how to fix it...thank you in advance

Comment: @LegendWhirlwind what do you get when executing the SQL statement with the replaced value directly? is this working?

Comment: the values in database are with collation Greek_CI_AI is there any problem with that? because when i tried the same query and the result was no again...and i tried another one query without  Javascript and Ajax just an input to insert a value ( that i already have in database) and now i have 2 categories with the same name

Answer (score -1):

Try using async false in your ajax.

```
$.post("action.php", {
    suggestion: name_location,
     type: 'POST',
     async: false //blocks window close
  }
```

Hope it might help you

Comment: That defies the concept of an asynchronous call